# Javascript generators syntax error in console

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, redux-saga

I have a problem when using generators. I get the following error in console:

> ERROR in ./app/redux/sagas/tracking.saga.js Module build failed:
>   SyntaxError:
>   C:/Workspace/teamable-frontend/app/redux/sagas/tracking.saga.js:
>   Unexpected token (18:4)

Here is the `package.json` :

```
{
 "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    ...
    }
...
}
```

And the loader in `webpack.config`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: ["transform-runtime"]
            }
        },
   ...
}
```

And the functions using generators:

```
import {put, call} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {takeEvery} from 'redux-saga';

import {LOAD} from '../../constants/ActionTypes';
import {loadTrackingItemsSuccess, loadTrackingItemsFail} from '../actions/tracking.actions';
import {getTrackingItems} from '../../mocks/ListMock'

function* loadTrackingItems() {
    try {
        const trackingItems = yield call(getTrackingItems);
        yield put(loadTrackingItemsSuccess(trackingItems));
    } catch(ex) {
        yield put(loadTrackingItemsFail(ex.toString()));
    }
}

export function watchTrackingItemsLoad() {
    yield* takeEvery(LOAD, loadTrackingItems);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yield` and `yield*` can only be used inside a generator function. Here:

```
export function watchTrackingItemsLoad() {
    yield* takeEvery(LOAD, loadTrackingItems);
}
```

you are using `yield*` inside a normal function. Either that function should also be a generator (`function* watchTrackingItemsLoad`), or you should return the generator object and let the caller deal with it (`return takeEvery(LOAD, loadTrackingItems);`).